# Android: block touches on fragment

Tags: android

I have an activity. In activity I have 2 fragments, and I want to block all touches on one of fragment and to unblock touches when user will click on first fragment. How to do that ? Fragment do not have onTouchEvent method

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In your fragment, in onCreateView, take the View you return and set it onTouchListener:

```
mContentView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.your_layout, null);
    mContentView.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            if(fragment is blocked)
              return true;
            else
             return false;
        }
    }); 
    return mContentView;
}
```

Comment: Is that possible to set new onTouch listener in runtime later?

Comment: For the fact that fragment is sometimes "touchable" and sometimes not, pass some kind of information about that to your fragment and, if it is touchable, let onTouch return false, otherwise true. I will edit my answer for clarity

Answer (score 0):

You could create your own layout (or better: override the one you are using) and override `public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent event)`